# Getting file names from txt file and copying them in C++

Tags: c++, string, move

I am trying to make a very simple program that reads a file name from a txt file, and move it from a specified source path to a specified destination path. For some reason it is not working.
It works properly. This is my code so far:

```
using namespace std;



int main(void)
{
    // Checking periodically if a new file exists and moving it
    

    // First, obtain the latest file name from the log. This will be the last line of the file "test1.txt" .
    ifstream MyFile;
    std::string LastLine;
    int NumLines = 0;
    MyFile.open("C:\\Users\\guili\\Desktop\\test folder\\test1.txt");
    if (MyFile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(MyFile, LastLine))
        {
        }
    }
    MyFile.close();

    // Move this file from "test folder" to "test folder2":
    std::string SourcePath = "C:/Users/guili/Desktop/test folder/";
    std::string DestinationPath = "C:/Users/guili/Desktop/test folder2/";
    std::string FileToBeMoved = SourcePath + LastLine ;
    std::string FileMovedTo = DestinationPath + LastLine;
    MoveFile(FileToBeMoved.c_str(), FileMovedTo.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

However, if I write:

```
MoveFile("C:/Users/guili/Desktop/test folder/test2.txt", "C:/Users/guili/Desktop/test folder 2/test2.txt");
```

Instead of

```
MoveFile(FileToBeMoved.c_str(), FileMovedTo.c_str());
```

It works properly. Does that have anything to do with the format the the function "MoveFile" requires?

Comment: Your code cannot compile, with or without the `MoveFile()` function call. Post a [mcve] as required here please!

Comment: Run your code under a debugger and step through your code to see what values end up being passed to `MoveFile`. There is a good chance that `LastLine` is the empty string.

Comment: Please remember that `it is not working` is not description of a problem. You must explain what is wrong and what is expected. Doesn't compile! What is the error message? ///  It crashes! Where? What is the call stack? /// Fails to open file! What are the error messages? Where are files /// .... .

Comment: What is C++ version? C++17 introduces `std::filesystem`!